# Duplicate form submission whtn button clicked?

Tags: javascript

I had a problem earlier that seemed to be solved but on closer inspection it is not fully fixed. I have a button that when clicked activates a javascript to send form data, then clear the form and then close hide the div. It works great apart from when I check the database it seems to submit twice? I have looked and cant see where the problem lies?

The button is :

```
<button name ='send' value="Send" type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Finish</button>
```

and the new JS code that duplicates entry is :

```
    $(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.output_message').text('Processing...'); 

      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        method: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
          if (result == 'success') {
            $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');
            form[0].reset();
            $('#5box').hide();
          } else {
            $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

and the old js(without clearing form and hiding div but does not duplicate entry) is :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-finish').on('click', function() {

        // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
        $('.output_message').text('Processing...'); 

        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            method: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');

                } else {
                    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                }
            }
        });

        // Prevents default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
        return false;   
    });
});
```

Comment: try and add an e. stopPropagation() and see if that helps

Comment: Hi, where shall I put that?

Comment: right above preventDefault

Comment: Nope mate, still sending twice!

Comment: is it your serverside code thats the problem? What does the DB entry file look like?

Comment: only 1 entry, and it worked fine before it was edited. I shall add old code before it sort of sort fixed.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include code that does not duplicate

Comment: The entry in the DB is 2 identical posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `return false` to the end of your event handler. [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

Answer (score 0):

remove button "type =submit" and

then use your old code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn-finish').on('click', function() {

        // Add text 'loading...' right after clicking on the submit button. 
        $('.output_message').text('Processing...'); 

        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            method: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');

                } else {
                    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                }
            }
        });

        // Prevents default submission of the form after clicking on the submit button. 
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide code for that as is not that clear? So what do I change "submit" to as I surely cannot put normal???

Comment: just remove it completely

Comment: No just remove the attribute type from the button. Final button syntax will be as follows
<pre>
<button name ='send' value="Send" class='btn btn-primary'>Finish</button>
</pre>

Comment: You have already registered the onclick functionality of the button in document load right?

Comment: Thats using my old method which already work 100%, it just didnt clear the form and hide the div, sorry I think we have got wires crossed here.

Comment: Make amendments in this area in your old code.
<pre>
success: function(result){
                if (result == 'success'){
                    $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');
                    form.reset();
                    //write your div id or class to hide
                    $("your div").hide();
                } else {
                    $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
                }
            }
</pre>

Comment: I have tried that before and now again, the form works but doesnt clear it and doesnt hide the div, the newer code does it but sends it twice!!!